# Gif image not working in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, gif

```
 from tkinter import * 
 photo = PhotoImage(file="C:\Temp\test\computer.gif")
 lbl = Label(root, image=photo, height="10", width="20").pack
```

I have absolutely no idea why this won't work it comes up with: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Temp\test\computer.gif.`

Comment: Keep in mind that in the above code your `lbl` isn't a Label object but rather a function object. If you want to call `pack` method, you need to do it in a seperate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows filenames always have to be entered as raw strings (in all of python, not just with tkinter). Also, you'll have to make a root window first. Try this:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Temp\test\computer.gif")
Label(root, image=photo, height="10", width="20").pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had the root = tk() and root.mainloop there before i just forgot to put it in the post. When I add the r it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not corrupted? Does is work with another file?

Comment: `lbl = None` here as well.